# Prove that if A and B are independent events then at least one of A and B is either the empty set or the sample space.

Tags: probability

Let $S = \{1, 2,..., p\}$, $R$ be the set of all subsets of $S$ and $P(A) = \frac{|A|}{p}$ for all $A \in R$. Suppose p is prime. Show that, if A and B are independent events then at least one of $A$ and $B$ is either $\varnothing$ or $S$.

My thoughts are there are $2^p$ possible subsets of S. If $A \in R$, then $|A| = 0, 1,\dots p$

So $2^p \sum{\frac{|A|}{p}} = 1$ if we sum over all $A \in R$. The sum is the binomial formula. After that...

Comment: HINT: Prove both cases individually.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @DonLarynx: What are the "both cases" you're talking about?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I've edited the post to include my thoughts.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, just did,   8-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm when either $\emptyset$ or $S$ occurs

Comment: @DonLarynx: Try to spell out what one of the cases is, concretely. The task is to prove that one of them occurs, so dividing into _which_ of them occurs makes no sense until you know that one of them does, and at that point you're already done.

Comment: @NasuSama, enough editing for one day --- you're bringing dozens of old questions to the front page, for no good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a=|A|,b=|B|,c=|A\cap B|$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then$$\frac cp=P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)=\frac ap\frac bp$$so $pc=ab$, so $ab$ is divisible by $p$. Since $p$ is prime, at least one of $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $p$. Since $0\le a,b\le p$, at least one of $a$ and $b$ is equal to $0$ or $p$.

Comment: wow! I was completely off. Thx!