# How would I show that for two independent events A and B at least on is either ∅ or Ω?

Tags: probability

Where Ω = {1,2,...,p}, all Ω are equally likely and p is prime how would I show that if A and B are independent events then at least one of A and B is either ∅ or Ω?

Comment: Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are equally likely.  Then $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$.  That is the definition of independence.  Now... how does the size of $A$ as an event in terms of number of elements relate to the probability of $A$ occurring?  How does $p$ being prime affect the relation between the two sides?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if A and B are independent events then at least one of A and B is either the empty set or the sample space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544774/prove-that-if-a-and-b-are-independent-events-then-at-least-one-of-a-and-b-is-eit)

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You have $P(A) = m/p$, $P(B) = n/p$, and $P(A\cap B) = k/p$, where $0\le m,n,k\le p$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $k/p = P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B) = mn/p^2$, hence $kp = mn$. As $p$ is prime, we either have that $m=0$ or $n =0$ (and then $k=0$) or $p$ must be a factor of $m$ or $n$. But $mn\le p$. So, $m=p$ or $n=p$.

Answer (score 1):

Since all values in $\Omega$ are equally likely, $P(A)=\# A/p$ for each $A\subseteq\Omega.$ Then $P(A\cap B)=\#(A\cap B)/p,$ but by independence, this equals $P(A)P(B)=\frac{\#A\#B}{p^{2}}.$ But for the equality $\#(A\cap B)p=\#A\#B$ to hold, either $\#A$ or $\#B$ must be divisible by $p,$ since $p$ is prime, and without loss of generality, let us say that this set is $A$. Since $\#A$ is in the set $\{0,\ldots,p\},$ we see that the only possibilities for $\#A$ are $0$ or $p,$ which correspond to $\varnothing$ or $\Omega,$ respectively.